# Error in json validation using Play2 with Scala

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework-2.3

I am using Play Framework 2.3 
Json request coming to my controller from U.I containing list of integers

i want to validate and  parse it to scala list so i am using **implicit Reads**

the problem i am facing is that when i implement my Read with only list like this

```
case class MgsValidation(  mgsidlist : List[Int]) 
object MgsValidation{
  implicit val readmgs : Reads[MgsValidation] = (
      (JsPath \ "mgslist").read[List[Int]]
      )(MgsValidation.apply _)
}
```

i get following error

> overloaded method value read with alternatives:
>
> [error]   (t: List[Int])play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[Int]]
>
> [error]   (implicit r:
>   play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[Int]])play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[Int]]
>
> [error]  cannot be applied to (List[Int] =>
>   models.JsonParsing.MgsValidation)
>
> [error]       (JsPath \ "mgslist").read[List[Int]]

but if I add any other random parameter like this

```
case class MgsValidation( uuid :Int , mgsidlist : List[Int]) 
object MgsValidation{
  implicit val deleteread : Reads[MgsValidation] = (
      (JsPath \ "uuid").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "mgslist").read[List[Int]]
      )(MgsValidation.apply _)
}
```

it works fine

but i want to simply validate and parse only List

how can i do this?

and also please tell me why is this **Reads** works fine with more than one parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick here: when you are using the combinator `and` your expression don't have the same type when you don't.

```
scala> :t (JsPath \ "mgslist").read[List[Int]]
play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[Int]]
```

but:

```
scala> :t ((JsPath \ "mgslist").read[List[Int]] and (JsPath \ "mgslist").read[List[Int]])
play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder[play.api.libs.json.Reads]#CanBuild2[List[Int],List[Int]] = play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder$CanBuild2@134e0422
```

The second type have the corresponding `apply` method defined on it, so you can just pass the case class' `apply` function afterwards. On the other side, `Reads` have `map` and `flatMap` defined on it, so you should use `map` to transform a `Reads[List[Int]]` to a `Reads[MsgValidation]`:

```
  (JsPath \ "mgslist").read[List[Int]].map(MgsValidation.apply _)
```

Comment: thanks it works, but can you please tell me where can i read more on this?

Comment: At the end of this paragraph: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Path-Reads, and here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Complex-Reads